# ASP.NET Core Worker Windows Service - Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services, worker

I developed ASP.NET Core-6 Worker Windows Service and deployed it.

Program.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build()

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();

    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddDIServices(configuration);
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

            // Register RabbitMQ connection
            services.AddSingleton<IConnection>(sp =>
            {
                var factory = new ConnectionFactory
                {
                    UserName = configuration["RabbitMQ:RMQUsername"],
                    Password = configuration["RabbitMQ:RMQPassword"],
                    HostName = configuration["RabbitMQ:RMQHost"],
                    Port = int.Parse(configuration["RabbitMQ:RMQPort"])
                };
                return factory.CreateConnection();
            });
        })
        .UseSerilog()
        .Build();
    host.Run();
}
}
```

I published the project, and copied the file in the Release folder.

Then I did:

sc create YourServiceName binPath= "C:\Path\To\Published\Directory\YourWorkerService.exe"

Then:

sc start YourServiceName

I got this error:

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Kindly help resolve this.

Comment: What application error is logged in the EventViewer?

Comment: What happened if you directly run the published dll or exe inside the published directory? Did you receive any error message? Also if you running at other server, you still facing the same error ?

Answer (score 1):

Your command is not good enough:

```
sc create YourServiceName binPath= "C:\Path\To\Published\Directory\YourWorkerService.exe" type= own start= auto depend= +TDI NetBIOS
```

The start=auto option instructs the computer to start the new "YourWorkerService" service
automatically when the computer is booted. The depend= +TDI NetBIOS option
tells the computer that it is dependent on the TDI group and on the NetBIOS
service.

PS: A space is required between an option and its value (for example, type= own. If the space is omitted, the operation fails.

Comment: When I followed your step, and decided to start it. I still got the same error :   Windows could not start on Local Computer.    Then:   Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Comment: Did u uninstall the previous version? Do it and retry the command. If is not working it maybe something else in your code that is crashing.

Comment: Yes I deleted the old one